# Show that $\sum_{r=1}^nu_r=u_{n+1}-(n+2)$

Tags: induction

Here's the information from the question

The sequence $u_1$, $u_2$, $u_3$,... is defined by
$$u_1=2\,,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,u_{k+1}=2u_k+1$$
Then I  was asked to prove that, for all $n\ge1$
$$u_n=3\times2^{n-1}-1$$
Now I'm being asked to show that
$$\sum_{r=1}^nu_r=u_{n+1}-(n+2)$$
This has left me very confused. I thought $\sum_{r=1}^nu_r$ just meant $u_n$? The sum from $r$ to $n$ where $r=1$. Problem is that
$$u_n\,\,{\ne}\,\,u_{n+1}-(n+2)$$
What does $u_r$ represent?

Comment: $u_r$ is the $r$th term of the sequence and $u_n$ is the $n$th term of the sequence defined recursively by $u_1 = 2$ and $u_{k + 1} = 2u_k + 1$.  $\sum_{r = 1}^n u_r$ means the sum of the first $n$ terms of the sequence, that is, $\sum_{r = 1}^n u_r = u_1 + u_2 + \cdots + u_n$.

Comment: @Thomas: Normally it is much better to edit/improve the existing version of the question as opposed to asking it anew. Improving a closed question often leads to it getting reopened. Now the answerers of the new version did not know about this one, which may have resulted in duplication of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that $\;u_n=3\cdot2^{n-1}-1\;$ , then carry on the sum explicitly:

$$\sum_{r=1}^nu_r=3\cdot\sum_{r=1}^n2^{r-1}-\sum_{r=1}^n1=3\frac{2^n-1}{2-1}-n=$$

$$=3\cdot2^n-3-n=\left(3\cdot2^{2n-1}-1\right)-2-n=u_{n+1}-(n+2)$$

Answer (score 1):

First, the sum should be read like this: "a sum of elements from 1-st to n-th is equal to (n+1)-st element minus (n+2)". For example, $u_1 + u_2 + u_3 = u_4 - (3+2)$ (you can verify this by calculating the corresponding elements.

I suggest you use the [mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Description) here: for $n = 1$, the sum is equal to one element: $\sum_{r=1}^1 u_r = u_1 = 2$. Now, the right side is easy: $u_{n+1} - (n+2) = u_2 - (1+2) = 2u_1 + 1 - (1+2) = 2*2 + 1 - 3 = 2$

So, we've proved this for $n = 1$.

Now, try to show that if it is true for any given $n$, then it will be true for the $n+1$. This concludes the induction!

Are you having trouble proving that $u_n = 3\times 2^{n-1} - 1$?

Comment: I've tried what you've said but my answer is $u_{n+1}-(n+3)$, the mark scheme is very breif but it says ${\sum}_{r=1}^nu_r={\sum}_{r=1}^n3{\times}2^{r-1}-n=3(2^n-1)-n$
I'm confused as to where the $2^{r-1}$ comes from?

Comment: actually my answer is $2u_{n+1}-(n+2)$