# Show that $\sum_{r=1}^nu_r=u_{n+1}-(n+2)$ given $u_1=2\,,u_{k+1}=2u_k+1\,,u_n=3\times2^{n-1}-1$

Tags: induction

The sequence $u_1$, $u_2$, $u_3$,... is defined by
$$u_1=2\,,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,u_{k+1}=2u_k+1$$
$$u_n=3\times2^{n-1}-1$$
Show that
$$\sum_{r=1}^nu_r=u_{n+1}-(n+2)$$
Prove that it is true for $n=1$ thus prove that $u_1=2$
$$\sum_{r=1}^nu_r=3\times2^{(1)}-1-((1)+2)=2$$
I guess you could alternatively use the fact that $u_1=2$ and use the equation $u_{k+1}=2u_k+1$
$$\sum_{r=1}^nu_r=2(2)+1-(1+2)=2$$
Now to prove that $$\sum_{r=1}^nu_r=u_{n+1}-(n+2)$$
you have to assume that it is true? Or assume that for any given value of $n$ that it is true, same thing though isn't it? Let $k$ be any given value (any integer greater than or equal to $1$ I assume), so $n=k$. Then by proving it true for $n=k+1$ I would be proving it true for $n=k$, is that correct?

$$\sum_{r=1}^ku_r=u_{k+1}-(k+2)$$
If this is equal to $u_1+u_2+u_3+...+u_k$, then
$$\sum_{r=1}^{k+1}u_r=u_{k+1}-(k+2)\color{red}{+u_{k+1}}$$
Since you're just adding the $(k+1)$th term onto the sum, $$u_1+u_2+u_3+...+u_k\color{red}{+u_{k+1}}$$
Now using $$u_{k+1}=2u_k+1,\,\,\,\,\,\,u_n=3\times2^{n-1}-1$$
I can show that 
$$\sum_{r=1}^{k+1}u_r=2(u_{k+1})-(k+2)$$
$$\implies2(2u_k+1)-(k+2)$$
$$\implies2(2(3\times2^{k-1}-1)+1)-(k+2)$$
$$\implies2(3\times2^k-2+1)-(k+2)$$
$$\implies3\times2^{k+1}-2-(k+2)$$
Now I need to prove that $$3\times2^{k+1}-2-(k+2)=2(u_{k+1})-(k+2)$$ by substituting $u_k=3\times2^{k-1}-1{\implies}u_{k+1}=3\times2^{(k+1)-1}-1$ into the RHS
$$2(u_{k+1})-(k+2)=2(3\times2^{(k+1)-1}-1)-(k+2)$$
$${\implies}3\times2^{k+1}-2-(k+2)$$

So it does work however part of me feels that this is not the right way to go about proving it. Also one question I have is about the very breif answer given in the mark scheme.

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}u_r=\sum_{r=1}^n3{\times}2^{r-1}-n=3(2^n-1)-n$$
Why have they changed $n-1$ for $r-1$ and subtracted $n$? What is the purpose of $u_r$?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Have I proved it? I'm slightly confused as to the mark schemes answer also. "Why have they changed $n−1$ for $r−1$ and subtracted $n$? What is the purpose of $u_r$?"

Comment: @ThomasWinkworth: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1229016/show-that-sum-r-1nu-r-u-n1-n2

Comment: @Alex M. If you're a mod delete that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, your way is correct but it is very *jugaado*. Explaining the given method:
$$u_r=3.2^{r-1}-1$$
Sigma both sides
$$
=\sum_{r=1}^n u_r =\sum_{r=1}^n (3.2^{r-1}-1)$$
Sigma of sum$$=\sum_{r=1}^n3.2^{r-1}-\sum_{r=1}^n 1 $$
Sigma of product$$
=3.\sum_{r=1}^n 2^{r-1}-\sum_{r=1}^n1$$
Geometric Series and constant sigma$$3\frac{2^n-1}{2-1}-n\\=3(2^n-1)-n$$

Comment: Why are you subtracting $\sum_{r=1}^n 1$? Doesn't $3.\sum_{r=1}^n 2^{r-1}-\sum_{r=1}^n1=\sum_{r=1}^n3.2^{r-1}-\sum_{r=1}^n 1$?

Comment: @ThomasWinkworth resee the post

Comment: Thanks for this by the way. Why does $3\cdot\sum_{r=1}^n 2^{r-1}=3\frac{2^n-1}{2-1}$ and $-\sum_{r=1}^n1=-n$?

Comment: @ThomasWinkworth first is a geometric series, and there is a formula for it and second is 1+1+...1 n times so = n.